# Trouble while getting id from id parent in another table

Tags: php

I tried to delete comment (from id_comment in comment table) while I got the id of the message in message table to view all of the comments from related message. It was success in database but in php redirected me to the unexpected link. when it's success for deleting comment, I wanna redirect to this **http://localhost/ta/home.php?apps=pesan&act=viewchat&id=3** (3 is example of id from message table). But the fact it redirected me to this **http://localhost/ta/home.php?apps=pesan&act=hapus&id=22** (22 is example of id from comment table).

This is my index.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['act'])){
$view = $_GET['act'];

require_once 'sys_pesan.php';
switch ($view) {
    case 'add':
        include 'apps/app_pesan/add.php';
        break;

    case 'hapus':
        include 'apps/app_pesan/viewchat.php';
        break;

    case 'viewchat':
        include 'apps/app_pesan/viewchat.php';
        break;

}
}else { if ($_SESSION['user_level']=='mahasiswa') {include 'apps/app_pesan/view.php';} elseif ($_SESSION['user_level']=='dosen') {include 'apps/app_pesan/dosenview.php';}
}

?>
```

This is a little code from sys_pesan.php about my problem

```
elseif ($view=='hapus') {
    $hapus = $db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM comment_bimbingan WHERE id_comment = :id");
    $hapus->bindParam(":id", $_GET['id']);
    $hapus->execute();
}
```

This is code about delete button from viewchat.php

```
<a href="?apps=pesan&act=hapus&id=<?php echo $row_2['id_comment']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Yakin untuk menghapus komentar?')" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
```

What should I change? I don't know how to redirected it back to link that getting id from the message table (related message only), not the comment table. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no server side confirmation of the delete action, You can just redirect to its referer link:

```
header('location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

But it's recommanded to double check the id retrieved through the get method before deleting the record.

Comment: Amazing. It works. Thank u so much. I never learn about this before. May Allah bless u always.

Comment: Glad it works for you, PS: In order to get informations from other table you can just select from the comments table and join it with messages table and you'll get information about the message which the selected comment is related to.

Comment: I'll try this suggestion. Thanks a lot.